# Scale tikz arrowhead

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to scale some tikz image using `scale=.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5}` which works for the text and all shapes but the arrow heads. How do I properly scale arrow heads?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (1,1)--(2,1);

  \begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm, scale=.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \draw[->,>=angle 60] (1,1)--(2,1);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=5.5cm, scale=.25, every node/.style={scale=0.25}]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \draw[->,>=angle 60] (1,1)--(2,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: row]

Comment: I can't touch the arrow itself since it is defined within a package (pgf-umlsd in the specific case)

Comment: maybe this -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155297/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155088/197451

Comment: No I don't really see a solution for my problem there.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to scale the line widths, the arrow heads will also scale.

If you do not want to scale the line widths, you can use `arrows.meta` to scale the arrow heads.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
  \draw[-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[]}] (1,1)--(2,1);

  \begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm, scale=.5]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \draw[-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale=0.5]}] (1,1)--(2,1);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=5.5cm, scale=.25]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \draw[-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale=0.25]}] (1,1)--(2,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I scale the line width? With the scope.

Comment: @white_gecko What I was referring to is this: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
  \draw[->] (1,1)--(2,1);
  \draw[ultra thin,->] (1,1.1)--(2,1.1);
  \draw[ultra thick,->] (1,0.8)--(2,0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. You are using the `arrows` library (as opposed to `arrows.meta`) which is deprecated. If you wish to transform the arrow size according to the scale factor, you may be interested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506249/194703).